# function sum(text) does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql

tengo una función muy sencilla que agrupa unos valores de el censo de Chile 2017. Las columnas de interés dicen a2007, a2008, a2009, etc que son los años y su población, todas son del tipo numeric pero no el problema que no puedo llamar a la columna, aparece el error

> ERROR:  function sum(text) does not exist
>   LINE 1: select sum(fecha_aux) from demo where edad be...
>                  ^
>   HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
>   QUERY:  select sum(fecha_aux)from demo where edad between $1 and $2
>   CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function demo_agrupada(numeric,numeric) line 18 at SQL statement
>   SQL state: 42883

La función es:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION demo_agrupada(edad_inicial numeric, edad_final numeric) 
RETURNS TABLE (agno text, poblacion numeric) AS $$
DECLARE
r text;
v numeric;
fecha_aux text;
fecha numeric;

BEGIN
for r in select ct.fecha,ct.texto from (values (2007,'a2007'),(2008,'a2008'),(2009,'a2009'),(2010,'a20010'),(2011,'cinco'),(2012,'cinco')
              ,(2013,'cinco'),(2014,'cinco'),(2015,'cinco'),(2016,'cinco'),(2017,'cinco')) as ct(fecha,texto)
LOOP
agno:=r;

fecha_aux='a'||r;
fecha_aux='"'||fecha_aux||'"';
--fecha_aux=fecha_aux::numeric;
--raise notice 'Value: %',r;
select sum(fecha_aux) into poblacion from demo where edad between $1 and $2;
return;
END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: estas realizando un sum de string , no de valores numericos, debes o hacer un CAST o guardar los valores en entero

Comment: Pero se están guardando como numeric donde dice "into poblacion". fecha_aux es el nombre de una columna pero no sé porqué pide que no sea text!. Gracias!